# How to export functions from library to application, not able to send through provider

Tags: angular, angular-library

I am trying to export a function from angular library to other application, i tried how i do the services, but getting error. what is the correct way?

here is my function: ( library )

```
export function monthDiff(dateFrom, dateTo) {
    dateFrom.setDate(1);
    dateTo.setDate(1);
    return dateTo.getMonth() - dateFrom.getMonth() +
        (12 * (dateTo.getFullYear() - dateFrom.getFullYear()));
}
```

if I import like:

```
import {monthDiff}  from '../../service'
```

and setting with provider like:

```
providers: [monthDiff]
```

getting error like:

```
Type '(date?: any, dd?: any) => string' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type '(date?: any, dd?: any) => string' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 25 more.
```

how to solve it?

Comment: write a service and function inside that service. here you are importing function not a service

Comment: yes, I agree. there is number of function like this and used in application. it will strange to move all them in service. is there any work-around to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can also  do one this create a file which can have many functions and export that in your component where you want to use its function like below

```
utils.ts


export default class Utils {
    static doSomething(val: string) { return val; }
    static monthDiff(dateFrom, dateTo) {
        dateFrom.setDate(1);
        dateTo.setDate(1);
      return dateTo.getMonth() - dateFrom.getMonth() +
        (12 * (dateTo.getFullYear() - dateFrom.getFullYear()));
    }
}
```

.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import Utils from './utils'


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(){
    let today = new Date();
    let form_date=new Date('2019-10-23')
    console.log(Utils.monthDiff(form_date,today))
  }
}
```

working link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdett3